# Restkit sending POST method instead of a GET method

Tags: api, websocket, mapping, restkit

I'm trying to create a method that retrieves available websocket servers from an api doc. My method to retrieve is:

```
-(void)getWebsocketServer: (GenericObject *)obj{

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]  postObject: obj
                                  path:@"v1/ambulances/websocket_servers.json"
                                  parameters:@{
 @"auth_token" : self.accessToken,
 @"api_key" : self.api_key,

 }

                                     success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                         RKLogInfo(@"Update drivers complete refresh view...");

                                     }

                                     failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                         RKLogError(@"Update Drivers failed with error: %@", error);

                                         [UIAlertView alertViewWithTitle:@"Cannot connect to server"
                                                                 message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Try again later", [error localizedDescription]]];

                                     }];

}
```

Here is the second part, the mapping:

```
  RKObjectMapping *websocketMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[GenericObject class]];

[websocketMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"servers"] ];



// Routes for Users

[self.objectManager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithName:kFindWebsockets
                                                        pathPattern:@"v1/ambulances/websocket_servers.json"
                                                             method:RKRequestMethodGET]];

RKResponseDescriptor *websocketDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:websocketMapping
                                                                                 pathPattern:@"v1/ambulances/websocket_servers.json"
                                                                                     keyPath:nil
                                                                                 statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

  [self.objectManager addResponseDescriptor:websocketDescriptor];
```

In the mapping I'm clearly using method:RKRequestMethodGET and yet when I make the request, charles (my web debugger) shows a POST method. This is driving me crazy! I have not used this path or method anywhere else so why is the request wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're calling:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]  postObject: obj ...
```

Where you should be calling:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]  getObjectsAtPathForRouteNamed:kFindWebsockets ...
```